# Conditional Validation ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, validation

I have 2 TextBoxes (textBoxA, textBoxB), both watched by their own RequiredFieldValidator. I want to 'enable' the RequiredFieldValidator for textBoxB just when textBoxA has a value (or meets some specific conditions).

Use cases:

Case 1
textBoxA = ""; -> Show Required Field Validation Message
textBoxB = ""; **-> Do not show validation message**

Case 2
textBoxA = "has a value";
textBoxB = ""; -> Show Required Field Validation Message

Case 3
textBoxA = "has a value";
textBoxB = "has a value too";

Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this situation I'd use a CustomValidator for textBoxB instead of the required field validator. In the server side validation method you can control the exact nature of the validation with something like this.

```
if (textBoxA.Text != string.Empty)
{
    args.IsValid = textBoxB.Text != string.Empty;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, that'll work for server side validations, but I'll have some dependant validations on the same page, and I don't want that that many postbacks

Answer (score 6):

You might want to use a [`CustomValidator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator%28VS.71%29.aspx) to do this. You'll need to implement the client side and server side validation. Something like *(off the top of my head and untested)*

Server side

```
protected void ServerValidation (object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{      
   if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBoxA))
       args.IsValid = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBoxB);

}
```

Client Side

```
function clientValidation(sender, args) {
    if (args.value !== "") {
       var textBoxB= document.getElementById('textBoxB');
       args.IsValid = (textBoxB.value !== "");
    }
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there's a declarative way to do it.  I've always done this by having a ValidatePage method where I set my validators to enabled or disabled and then call Page.Validate at the end (and then proceed or render based on Page.IsValid).

So, either

```
validator2.IsEnabled = textBoxA.Text.Trim().Length > 0
```

or something like that.

That's pseudo code btw...I haven't done ASP.NET in some time now.

Answer (score 0):

What I do is to change the Validation Group according to requirement, for example, you may assign the validation group to the textBoxB to a value different or the same that textBoxA.ValidationGroup & the submit control, this may be done in textBoxB's  Onchange.

Validators which are evaluated are all that correspond to the same validation group of the submit control.