# required fields and asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, textbox

im working on an .aspx page in Visual Studio.

I want to have a text box that is followed by a drop down menu.

if the user enters any input in the text box id like for it and the drop down menu to both be required before the corresponding button can be clicked.

is the best way to do this to use a RequiredFieldValidator ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you attempt to do is Conditional Validation
This question is similar to your question for [Conditional Validation ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711819/conditional-validation-asp-net)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `RequiredFieldValidator` would work well for your scenario.  Just be sure to enable it or disable based on 'if the user enters any input in the text box'

Answer (score 0):

You can create validators for both fields and onblur of the textbox enable/disable the validators using javascript.

**HTML**:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txt" onblur="enableVaidators();" />
```

**Javascript**:

```
function enableValidators()
{
   var val_Test = document.getElementById('<%=val_Test.ClientID%>');
   var enableValidators = true;

   // Perform check on whether to enable or disable based on your scenario

   ValidatorEnable(val_Test, enableValidators);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

how about using jquery?

everything is done on the client-side:

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/

Answer (score 0):

I would use a CustomValidator which implemented logic based on the state of the TextBox.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.aspx

Comment: ok, i think this would work, but the second field is a dropdown menu, and i want it to start off as blank, so the user can have it be null if they would like to.  so would i just have a asp:DropDownList with some asp:ListItem's and have the first item be blank?  would that args.IsValid still work?

Comment: i just need to get the dropdown items to load dynamically